# Pinterest Pin It button accepts all fields but doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

having a problem with my pinterest button..

code is as follows:

```
var pinit = '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + window.location + '&media=' + $(this).attr('src') + '&description=test" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>'
```

and renders to this URL:

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://example.com/blog/?p=37&media=http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wpim1.png&description=test
```

But when you actually 'pin it' it just refreshes as you see, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why..

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried encoding your url data? like `...?url='+ encodeURIComponent(window.location)+'&...` and the rest of your url data?

Comment: Yeah, no luck with that unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution?

Don't try and pin images that are stores locally ahaha.

<<< Idiot.